# Php 5.3.3 conversion method

Tags: php

I am using centos and normally when I run yum update it accordingly updates the stables version of software. I know my php is 5.3.3 is old but the built is  (built: Aug 11 2016 20:33:53). I have an issue to convert from hexadecimal to binary format.

Currently I am using this method  `echo "bin is : ".decbin(hexdec("AA"));`
First I convert from hex to decimal then further I convert that decimal to binary. I am not sure is this a valid method and will I face any issue like the number of bits will be less than 8?

Comment: that looks valid to me.  What's the issue those two functions have been around since php4 (And exist in php7).  Decbin will return as little as 1 bit, so I don't see any issues

Comment: @forbs say my hex will always be 2 character and will it return always 8 bit for the binary or must I add some extra logic there with the extra 0?

Comment: Just because it has been built in the last few weeks, it doesn't make it safe, supported or sane.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois so what is your best suggestion then problem with Centos it does not agree with manual build so I worried on that to cause instability on the server

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not agree with manual build"?

Comment: See https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/

Comment: @CharlotteDunois are you suggesting to upgrade via this repo? Will it cause any stability issue ? Secondly will it have any impact on my existing codes?

Comment: I'm not explicitely saying you should upgrade via this repo, more you should upgrade, an option would be via this repo. I'm using PHP 7 myself in production (it's a debian server though), and I don't notice any instability. It's as stable as PHP5 (but faster and better). Yes, there are gonna be impacts on your existing code, like backwards incompatible changes, deprecated features, etc. Read the migration guides from 5.3 to 5.4, 5.4 to 5.5, 5.5 to 5.6 and 5.6 to 7.0. They're all on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.php).

Comment: @CharlotteDunois what repo then you suggest for upgrade if not this? I mean any other repo?

Comment: I'm not using CentOS myself, so I can't suggest any repo specifically. But I've heard from others using CentOS, that they use this repo.

Comment: you can always throw it into a sprintf("%08d",$mybinvalue); if you want 8 digit padded bin.  Since decbin returns a string it wont convert it back to a decimal, but it will pad the needed zeros

Comment: So its safe to what that sprintf("%08d",$mybinvalue); cause I need it to be 8 digits due to some other calculation I need to perform. I dont get you when your say it will pad the needed zeros? So do I need that extra step or should I leave as per what have been done?